# Why does Cosmo need the space suit in Guardian of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

The dog's helmet was open in the movie so it must have been able to breathe. It was kept by the Collector in a cell. It's not like the dog is going into space any time soon: so, why does it still have a space suit on? Even at the end of the movie post credit, Cosmo was running around outside of its container without issues so we know the cell did not contain any kind of special air that the dog needs.

On a side note, I see an issue with potty with that space suit.

Comment: He likes wearing his spacesuit. Don't judge him.

Comment: @phantom42 I am not judging him, on the contrary, I was hoping to make him more confortable

Comment: I assumed it was Laika.

Comment: Laika was a different breed

Comment: http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmo - His uniform is preserved because he's a museum piece.

Comment: @Richard I will buy that assumption as it does make sense. I am still wondering about the potty issue

Comment: @Huangism -http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops

Comment: @Richard Oh I mean how would the dog potty with that space suit on. I don't actually want to see the dog doing that although I see it everyday at home. If you post the uniform comment as an answer, I believe it is a good one

Comment: I'd imagine the same way most astronauts go to the bathroom in space while wearing a suit: space-diapers that are removed and replaced later.

Comment: @phantom42 so the Collector's servants does this?

Comment: One of his servants is seen cleaning, so yes, most likely.

Comment: For some reason Cosmo didn't occur to me and I thought it was Laika "rescued" by the collector rescued and was the real reason they lost life signs after a couple hours. First earthling in space seems like something he might collect.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laika

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Why would Cosmo keep the spacesuit he was shot into space with? He doesn't need the space suit. He wants it. He is nostalgic for Earth and has (at least before meeting NOVA in the comics and the Guardians in the movie) no way to get back home.

- In the Guardians of the Galaxy movie, Cosmo is an exhibit of the Collector. In the comics, Cosmo was the "sheriff" of Nowhere, so there is a bit of a medium conflict. In the comics, he was still wearing his Soviet-era suit even though he had people to help him, support him and provide him with whatever technology he might have needed.
- Cosmo is a dog from a Soviet Space Program who was whisked away into an experimental wormhole. When he arrived on the other side he found his intelligence greatly increased and he was now blessed with incredible psychic abilities.
- However, living on Nowhere (before he was captured by the Collector) was now very far from home and nostalgic. While he could get other clothing or wear none at all, he is homesick for his home planet and wears the only artifact he can assure has come from Earth.
- As an exhibit of the Collector, odds are, knowing the Collector's habits, the suit has been modified to meet any needs his "exhibits" might have. If he didn't want to change the suit in any way, he may have had robots or servants to "clean up" after Cosmo. Since the suit came with the dog, from the Collector's perspective, it adds to Cosmo's "value" since the suit was from an early civilization's space program.
- In the movies, he seems bent on staying with the Collector. In the comics, he has run off to work with the Guardians of the Galaxy.

Comment: I guess you can say that with the increased intelligence, he knows how to take care of his waste ;)

Comment: Assuming he isn't locked up in an exhibit case...

Comment: Maybe the Collector uses the display case as a crate haha